# How do I create a cookie in svelte and access it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cookies, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to create a cookie in svelte (and I am also using svelte kit) and access it. I am want to use the cookie for authentication purposes, more specifically, to store a JWT Token.

I am tried implementing pure JS code, such as `getCookie()` and `setCookie()` as shown here [W3Schools - JavaScript Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). But I can't get access to the document. I have also tried serialize from the `cookie` npm package, as shown below, and I have also tried using browser as shown below.

```
import { serialize } from "cookie";
```

```
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
```

Comment: I use `js-cookie` for my projects, and it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can e.g. set a cookie in a [form action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions). If you want to be able to read it in the browser, you have to disable `HttpOnly` (in general you should avoid this, as it makes cross site scripting vulnerabilities worse).

A simple example:

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
    export let form: { error?: string; } | null;
</script>

<form method="post" use:enhance>
    <label>Login <input type="text" name="login" /></label>
    <label>Password <input type="password" name="password" /></label>
    {#if form?.error}<p>{form.error}</p>{/if}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

```js
// +page.server.ts
import { fail, redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { Actions } from './$types';

export const actions: Actions = {
    default: async ({ request, cookies }) => {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        const login = formData.get('login');
        const password = formData.get('password');

        if (login == 'admin' && password == '...') {
            cookies.set(
                'auth', '42',
                {
                    path: '/',
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
                    httpOnly: false, // <-- if you want to read it in the browser
                },
            );
            redirect(302, '/');
        }
        return fail(400, { error: 'Invalid login or password' });
    },
}
```

The cookie can be read from `document.cookie`, note that this will throw an error during SSR, so you have to check `browser` or read it in `onMount`.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna set it in script tag in a file, then you need to wait till the DOM is loaded. Which means that you can access `document.cookie` in a function called by an element or you can use `onMount` lifecycle.

Something like this:

```js
onMount(() => {
        document.cookie = "theme=light";
});
```

I know the post is old, but it took me some time to solve this as well. I hope it can help somebody.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a comment on @brunnerh's answer, last sentence.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35506040)